# How to go to another view by clicking on the textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a simple question, how to connect a textfield to another Control view, if I click on the textfield, instead of show the keyboard it jump to another view

Thanks for answers

Comment: y don u use button for that.

Comment: may be add gesture recoginzer to text field?

Comment: check out now i have added code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the delegate method of the TextField, wich is `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, add code that go from current View to another View.

Or you can use tap gasture recognizer on TextField to get the touch.

Here is the code:

create a TextFied in your IB and connect it to .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTF;
```

And in .m file add this

```
@synthesize firstTF;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstTF.delegate= self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    secondViewController *ainfoController = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:ainfoController animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I dont know what exactly what that means, could you write example please, i am new in iphone programing, The only connect i do for now  is in storyboard

Comment: Ok, but i dont understand this ->secondViewController *ainfoController = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:ainfoController animated:YES];

Comment: Thats creating a new View controller? I create a View controller in storyboard

Comment: try this code:- ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Ok, it worked, but i don't want to create new viewController like this,i create it in storyboard i want jump to it by the code you posted, Is there a option? Something like ID?

Comment: you are not creating new view controller you are just initializing your existing viewcontroller programmetically ,so dont worry about it.add name of viewcontroller which you want to initialize instead of vieconttroller in our code.

Comment: Finnaly, i solved by a button, I have there 3 textfields so averyone jump to the function, so I choose the easy way

Comment: @Jakub easy way is better way :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the Textfield by code then,

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

and add this method

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     // you can add the code for present a new viewController here
     return NO;
}
```

make sure you have added UITextFieldDelegate in your .h file

Comment: ok, but i try debug, and when i click to the textfield it doesn't jump to the function - (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: did you add the UITextFieldDelegate to your .h file like this   @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Yes I add, i add it earlier because i need to hide keyboura

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get in why you need this but as a developer we do firmly believe to implement all scenarios, so in your case, you can achieve the same by following the any one beneath mentioned tacts:

1) In this approach, you need to override the textfieldshouldbegin delegate and use the navigate code for moving from one screen to another and don't forget to call resignFirstResponder here.

2) While in this second approach what you can do, just overlap a custom button(with neither image nor any text) and just on his click event method write your navigation code to move another screen.

Do that stuff, you'll get what you want and in case still you find any difficulty just shout over me.